Zero sets of trigonometric polynomials defined recursively
I have a family of multivariate trignometric polynomials $f_\ell,g_\ell : \mathbb R^{\ell} \to \mathbb R$. I can write $f_\ell$ and $g_\ell$ as follows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{\ell} \\
g_{\ell}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \cos x_\ell  &  -\beta \sin x_\ell  \\
\alpha \sin x_\ell &  \beta \cos x_\ell  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{\ell-1} \\
g_{\ell-1}
\end{pmatrix} \quad \quad
\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb R^\times
$$
Here $f_{\ell-1}, g_{\ell-1}$ are to be thought to similar polynomials that depend on only the first $\ell-1$ variables. Can I relate the zero sets of $f_{\ell}$ and $g_{\ell}$ to that of $f_{\ell-1}$ and $g_{\ell-1}$? Can I relate topological properties of the zero set (such as the number of connected components) of $f_{\ell}$ and $g_{\ell}$ to that of $f_{\ell-1}$ and $g_{\ell-1}$?
Does anyone know of any literature on topological properties of zero sets of inductively defined polynomials?
Note: We can assume that $f_1 = \cos ( x_1)$ and $g_1 = \sin ( x_1)$. If it helps, we can take $\beta = 1/\alpha$.

Are those formulas defining $f_\ell$ and $g_\ell$? What are the initial $f_0$ and $g_0$ or $f_1$ and $g_1$?

I have edited the question.

Too bad the $+$ in the definition of $f_\ell$ isn't a $-$, otherwise $f_\ell$ would just be $\cos(x_1+\cdots+x_\ell)$ and $g_\ell$ would just be $\sin(x_1+\cdots+x_\ell)$.

I have edited the question again with a bit more details.

This is the same as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/480990/zero-sets-of-sums-of-multivariate-polynomials-defined-recursively-with-mutually ?
